# How to calculate with previous values in a Pandas MultiIndex DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have the following MultiIndex dataframe.

```
                         Close     ATR     
Date          Symbol     
1990-01-01    A          24        2       
1990-01-01    B          72        7      
1990-01-01    C          40        3.4 

1990-01-02    A          21        1.5     
1990-01-02    B          65        6        
1990-01-02    C          45        4.2   

1990-01-03    A          19        2.5    
1990-01-03    B          70        6.3       
1990-01-03    C          51        5
```

I want to calculate three columns:

- `Shares` = previous day's `Equity` * 0.02 / `ATR`, rounded down to whole number
- `Profit` = `Shares` * `Close`
- `Equity` = previous day's `Equity` + sum of `Profit` for each `Symbol`

`Equity` has an initial value of 10,000.

The expected output is:

```
                         Close     ATR     Shares     Profit     Equity
Date          Symbol     
1990-01-01    A          24        2       0          0          10000
1990-01-01    B          72        7       0          0          10000
1990-01-01    C          40        3.4     0          0          10000

1990-01-02    A          21        1.5     133        2793       17053
1990-01-02    B          65        6       33         2145       17053
1990-01-02    C          45        4.2     47         2115       17053

1990-01-03    A          19        2.5     136        2584       26885
1990-01-03    B          70        6.3     54         3780       26885
1990-01-03    C          51        5       68         3468       26885
```

I suppose I need a `for loop` or a `function` to be applied to each row. With these I have two issues. One is that I'm not sure how I can create a `for loop` for this logic in case of a `MultiIndex` dataframe. The second is that my dataframe is pretty large (something like 10 million rows) so I'm not sure if a `for loop` would be a good idea. But then how can I create these columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution can surely be cleaned up, but will produce your desired output. I've included your initial conditions in the construction of your sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['1990-01-01','1990-01-01','1990-01-01','1990-01-02','1990-01-02','1990-01-02','1990-01-03','1990-01-03','1990-01-03'],
    'Symbol': ['A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C'],
    'Close': [24, 72, 40, 21, 65, 45, 19, 70, 51],
    'ATR': [2, 7, 3.4, 1.5, 6, 4.2, 2.5, 6.3, 5],
    'Shares': [0, 0, 0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'Profit': [0, 0, 0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

Gives:

```
         Date Symbol  Close  ATR  Shares  Profit
0  1990-01-01      A     24  2.0     0.0     0.0
1  1990-01-01      B     72  7.0     0.0     0.0
2  1990-01-01      C     40  3.4     0.0     0.0
3  1990-01-02      A     21  1.5     NaN     NaN
4  1990-01-02      B     65  6.0     NaN     NaN
5  1990-01-02      C     45  4.2     NaN     NaN
6  1990-01-03      A     19  2.5     NaN     NaN
7  1990-01-03      B     70  6.3     NaN     NaN
8  1990-01-03      C     51  5.0     NaN     NaN
```

Then use `groupby()` with `apply()` and track your `Equity` globally. Took me a second to realize that the nature of this problem requires you to group on two separate columns individually (`Symbol` and `Date`):

```
start = 10000
Equity = 10000

def calcs(x):

    global Equity

    if x.index[0]==0: return x #Skip first group

    x['Shares'] = np.floor(Equity*0.02/x['ATR'])
    x['Profit'] = x['Shares']*x['Close']
    Equity += x['Profit'].sum()

    return x

df = df.groupby('Date').apply(calcs)
df['Equity'] = df.groupby('Date')['Profit'].transform('sum')
df['Equity'] = df.groupby('Symbol')['Equity'].cumsum()+start
```

This yields:

```
         Date Symbol  Close  ATR  Shares  Profit   Equity
0  1990-01-01      A     24  2.0     0.0     0.0  10000.0
1  1990-01-01      B     72  7.0     0.0     0.0  10000.0
2  1990-01-01      C     40  3.4     0.0     0.0  10000.0
3  1990-01-02      A     21  1.5   133.0  2793.0  17053.0
4  1990-01-02      B     65  6.0    33.0  2145.0  17053.0
5  1990-01-02      C     45  4.2    47.0  2115.0  17053.0
6  1990-01-03      A     19  2.5   136.0  2584.0  26885.0
7  1990-01-03      B     70  6.3    54.0  3780.0  26885.0
8  1990-01-03      C     51  5.0    68.0  3468.0  26885.0
```

Comment: This works. I have to add that since I had a `MultiIndex` dataframe, I had to perform a `.reset_index()` on the dataframe. Furthermore, I got an error for the line `x['Shares'] = np.floor(Equity*0.02/x['ATR'])`: `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'floor'`. I solved this by converting it to `x['Shares'] = np.floor((Equity*0.02/x['ATR']).astype(float))`. Thank you.

Comment: Glad this worked for you, and I appreciate you taking the time to include the slight modifications you had to make to the solution!

Comment: What if I want to bound the calculation of `Shares` to a condition included in another column `Cond`, otherwise forward fill `Shares` values grouped by `Symbol`? Like if `x[Cond] == True` then `np.floor((Equity*0.02/x['ATR']).astype(float))` else `ffill() previous Shares value`. I've tried to play around with the function you wrote but I'm struggling to access previous row's `Shares` value. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: This would be better served as a separate question. The reason I declared `Equity` as `global` was to be able to continuously query the previous value and then proceed to increment it during the current group iteration. You may need to do something similar, but posting as another question may get better visibility.

Answer (score 0):

can you try using shift and groupby? Once you have the value of the previous line, all columns operations are straight forward.

```
table2['previous'] = table2['close'].groupby('symbol').shift(1)

table2

date    symbol      close   atr     previous

1990-01-01  A   24  2   NaN
            B   72  7   NaN
            C   40  3.4     NaN
1990-01-02  A   21  1.5     24
            B   65  6   72
            C   45  4.2     40
1990-01-03  A   19  2.5     21
            B   70  6.3     65
            C   51  5   45
```